# Bind a particular service to Broker

Tags: wsdl, messagebroker

I am new to Message Broker.And I am in project that involves web-services.
**I have created a WSDL using the XSD's.**
Now how to bind the service with broker ,so its accessible from the outside.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the wsdl on to a SOAPInput node then setup the URI you want to use and deploy the resulting application.

Comment: Or, alternatively, "write a message broker flow that acts as a proxy between the backend service and the client." Both are *good* answers.